# MySql Error 150 - Foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-error-150

When I execute the follow two queries (I have stripped them down to absolutely necessary):

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE foo(id INT PRIMARY KEY);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE bar ( id INT, ref INT, FOREIGN KEY (ref) REFERENCES foo(id)) ENGINE InnoDB;
```

I get the following error:
    ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table './test/bar.frm' (errno: 150)

Where the **** is my error? I haven't found him while staring at this for half an hour.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From [`FOREIGN KEY` Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

> If you re-create a table that was
>   dropped, it must have a definition
>   that conforms to the foreign key
>   constraints referencing it. It must
>   have the right column names and types,
>   and it must have indexes on the
>   referenced keys, as stated earlier. If
>   these are not satisfied, MySQL returns
>   error number 1005 and refers to error
>   150 in the error message.

My *suspicion* is that it's because you didn't create `foo` as InnoDB, as everything else looks OK.

Edit: from the same page -

> Both tables must be InnoDB tables and they must not be TEMPORARY tables.

Comment: A bit of quick testing, creating a `foo` as above with MyISAM, and a `bar` with InnoDB, suggests that that's the case - try double-checking your table type for `foo`.

Comment: Even when both tables were InnoDB, I still had the same problem. I fixed it by created the index on the referred table before creating the foreign key.

Comment: It doesn't help that MySQL Workbench 6.3 seems to randomly change the engine type to MyISAM from InnoDB when I'm creating new tables.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the command `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` to get more specific information about the error.

It will give you a result with a `Status` column containing a lot of text.

Look for the section called LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR which could for example look like this:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
190215 11:51:26 Error in foreign key constraint of table `mydb1`.`contacts`:
Create  table `mydb1`.`contacts` with foreign key constraint failed. You have defined a SET NULL condition but column 'domain_id' is defined as NOT NULL in ' FOREIGN KEY (domain_id) REFERENCES domains (id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT contacts_teams_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES teams (id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT' near ' ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT contacts_teams_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES teams (id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT'.
```

Comment: Agree! It shows a section "Last foreign key error", which in my case told me the target field name of a foreign key constraint was not found. This is more helpful than a sheer "Error 150" ;-)

Comment: In my case I had forgotten to set the column to allow NULL, and put SET NULL on the constraint. But I only found out the reason by running `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`

Comment: This should be the top answer! Although it could help to know there is a LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR section in the 'Status' column output for this query. As @MarekStanley also states clearly.

Answer (score 4):

To create a foreign key ,

1. both the main column and the reference column must have same definition.
2. both tables engine must be InnoDB.

You can alter the engine of table using this command , please take the backup before executing this command.

alter table [table name] ENGINE=InnoDB;

Comment: "must have same definition" was same charset encoding for me

Comment: "must have same definition" was same same column flags for me:  The existing primary key I was referencing was UNSIGNED, so I had to make my new table's column that also to foreign key on the first

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, for those who are having this also:

check the table name of the referenced table

I had forgotten the 's' at the end of my table name

eg table Client --> Clients

:)

Answer (score 1):

Apart form many other reasons to end up with MySql Error 150 (while using InnoDB), One of the probable reason, is the undefined `KEY` in the create statement of the table containing the column name referenced as a foreign key in the relative table.

Let's say the create statement of master table is -

`CREATE TABLE 'master_table' (

 'id' int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

 'record_id' char(10) NOT NULL,

 'name' varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

 'address' varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

 PRIMARY KEY ('id')

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

and the create syntax for the relative_table table where the foreign key constraint is set from primary table -

`CREATE TABLE 'relative_table' (

 'id' int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

 'salary' int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

 'grade' char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

 'record_id' char(10) DEFAULT NULL,

 PRIMARY KEY ('id'),

 CONSTRAINT 'fk_slave_master' FOREIGN KEY ('record_id') REFERENCES 'master' ('record_id')

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

This script is definitely going to end with MySql Error 150 if using InnoDB.

To solve this, we need to add a `KEY` for the The column `record_id` in the `master_table` table and then reference in the `relative_table` table to be used as a foreign_key.

Finally, the create statement for the `master_table`, will be -

`CREATE TABLE 'master_table' (

 'id' int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

 'record_id' char(10) NOT NULL,

 'name' varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

 'address' varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

 PRIMARY KEY ('id'),

 KEY 'record_id' ('record_id')

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

Answer (score 0):

I had very same problem and the reason was the "collation" of columns was different. One was latin1 while the other was utf8

Answer (score 0):

This may also happen if you have not given correct column name after "references" keyword.