# How to create TINYINT(1) datatype in mysql database?

Tags: mysql

I'm creating table in mysql database but it is giving error...

```
    CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `EC_TIMETABLE` (
  `S_ID` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `SKILLSET_ID` VARCHAR(30) NULL ,
    START_DT DATETIME NULL,
    END_DT DATETIME NULL,
    REPEAT TINYINT(1) NULL,
    ALL_DAY TINYINT(1) NULL,
    CLASS_DURATION INT NULL,
    COURSE_DURATION INT NULL,
    REPEAT_TYPE VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    REPEAT_EVERY INT NULL,
    REPEAT_DAYS VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    REPEAT_FROM DATE NULL,
    REPEAT_TO DATE NULL,
    COURSE_FEE INT NULL,
    ATTENDEE_MIN INT NULL,
    ATTENDEE_MAX INT NULL,
    SEARCH_KEY TINYTEXT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (`SKILLSET_ID` )
    REFERENCES `EC_SKILLSET` (`S_ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

But it giving Error:

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'REPEAT TINYINT(1) NULL, ALL_DAY TINYINT(1) NULL, CLASS_DURATION
>   INT NULL' at line 6

How to solve this one..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`REPEAT` is a Reserved Keyword. You can still use it but you need to wrap it with backticks.

```
`REPEAT` TINYINT(1) NULL,
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)

I suggest that you don't use such keywords on the reserve list to avoid neck pain in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I believe REPEAT is a keyword in MySQL. Try renaming your column.

Answer (score 1):

First you shouldn't use REPEAT because this is reserved by mysql and secondly take a look at [MySql Error 150 - Foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825362/mysql-error-150-foreign-keys) because you have another error concerning foreign keys.

Comment: what's wrong with the foreign key?

Comment: ahh sorry stupid me, it should work just fine. Sorry, responded too fast.