# MySQL failing to create a new table using Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I only get an error 150 when I run this.  The other tables are InnoDB, the types are primary key, and the data types match.  So I can't see what I'm doing wrong, (and I see no obvious syntax errors).  Any ideas?

```
CREATE TABLE grouptosite (
  groups_id BIGINT(20),
  usertogroup_groupID BIGINT(20),
usertogroup_userID BIGINT(20),
  usertosite_id INT(10),

  gts_id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (gts_id),
index (gts_id),
index (groups_id),
  index (usertogroup_groupID), 
index (usertogroup_userID),
  index (usertosite_id), 

FOREIGN KEY (groups_id)
    REFERENCES groups(id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  FOREIGN KEY (usertogroup_groupID, usertogroup_userID)
    REFERENCES usertogroup(groupID, userID)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  FOREIGN KEY (usertosite_id)
    REFERENCES usertosite(id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT  
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: This should solver your issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825362/mysql-error-150-foreign-keys

Comment: What do the `groups`, `usertogroup` and `usertosite` tables look like?

Comment: Are you sure your columns are the same type? I first created the usertosite table with the id of BIGINT (following the same pattern of the other tables), but the grouptosite.usertosite_id field was INT. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d821a

Comment: Xecaps12 is correct.  I can't give you the checkmark, but that solved it.

Comment: @xecaps12: Please consider reposting your suggestion as an answer. I believe having this question answered (*both* actually and formally) would be a valuable addition to the site. Even though this case appears to have been perfectly covered by the docs, adding prominence to the `int`/`bigint` confusion may be helpful to the general public.

Comment: @AndriyM It seemed like a simple typo and user2600629 had the right idea, but your right, clarity is good and I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your columns are the same type? I first created the `usertosite` table with the id of BIGINT (following the same pattern of the other tables), but the `grouptosite.usertosite_id` column was INT: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d821a.

As mentioned in another comment, datatypes for [foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) need to be the same.