# Migrating old database to new database

Tags: mysql

I am installing new bugzilla server and importing old database to new bugzilla server

old mysql Server version : mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.51a, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

old OS Version:  Debian GNU/Linux 5.0 \n \l

New Mysql Server Version : mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.49, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

New OS Version: Debian GNU/Linux 8 \n \l

I am importing database like below

mysql -u root -p bugs < /home/chelsio/backup-05-25-2016-19-00.sql

I am getting below error

ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 6237: Can't create table 'bugs.bugs' (errno: 150).

SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; output

### LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR

160527 10:27:59 Error in foreign key constraint of table bugs/bugs:
 FOREIGN KEY (`component_id`) REFERENCES `components` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_bugs_product_id_products_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_bugs_reporter_profiles_userid` FOREIGN KEY (`reporter`) REFERENCES `profiles` (`userid`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30401 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8:
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.

I dont have any knowledge on mysql I am new mysql world. Please help.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4061293/1331451, http://stackoverflow.com/q/825362/1331451 - probably you need to  turn off constraint checking in your backup dump.

Comment: Also, please [check your question history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2739700/sagar?tab=questions) and accept answers that solved the respective problems. See [ask] and take the [tour] if you don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Simbabque tried but no luck, SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

Comment: @simbabque; sorry I used it properly now database imported correctly thanks